# Zf2 child route not working when it has one more child.

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I am using zf2 and I have defined child routes like this.

```
'routes' => array(
            'test' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/test',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Test\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Test',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'testABC' => array(
                            'type' => 'Literal',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/abc',
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'action'     => 'abc',
                                    ),
                            ),
                            'child_routes' => array(
                                    'testABCDEF' => array(
                                            'type' => 'Segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'    => '/def/:id',
                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                            'action'     => 'def',
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    'testABCXYZ' => array(
                                            'type' => 'Segment',
                                            'options' => array(
                                                    'route'    => '/xyz/:id',
                                                    'defaults' => array(
                                                            'action'     => 'xyz',
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                             ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

In this only one route is not working, I don't know why?

- localhost/test **Working**
- localhost/test/abc **Not working**
- localhost/test/abc/def/1 **Working**
- localhost/test/abc/xyz/1 **Working**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because your `testABC` route is missing the `may_terminate` option.

If it had no children, it would implicitly terminate, but since it has children, you must inform the router of the possibility explicitly (just like you did with its parent `test` route.)

```
'testABC' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/abc',
        'defaults' => array(
            'action'     => 'abc',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true, // inform the router
    'child_routes' => (
         // ...
    ),
),
```

Comment: thanks a lot...now its working..Now I came to know what's the use 'may_terminate'.